# How to export a type in MEF as if the Export Attribute had been applied to that type?

Tags: .net, mef, composition, system.componentmodel

I would like to dynamically apply the MEF Export attribute to a type at run-time, exactly as if the type had had an Export attribute applied at compile time.

Is there a simple way to do this?

Barring that, is there a complex way to do this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you can afford to use .NET 4.5 (which means dropping windows XP support), you can now use MEF's [attribute-less registration](https://mindinthewater.blogspot.com/2011/03/mef-attribute-less-registration.html) aka [Convention Model](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/hammett/mefs-convention-model).

In .NET4 or earlier MEF preview releases this is not supported out of the box, but MEF can still be extended by creating your own implementations of [ExportProvider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.hosting.exportprovider?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0) or [ComposablePartCatalog](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.composition.primitives.composablepartcatalog?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).

The [MEF Contrib Fluent Definition Provider](http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Provider%20Model%20Fluent%20Definition%20Provider) is such an implementation which allows you to register imports and exports by method calls.

The [MEF Contrib Configurable Definition Provide](http://mefcontrib.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Provider%20Model%20Configurable%20Definition%20Provider)r is another which allows you to set up the imports and exports in an XML file.

Yet another option is to do the registration with [Autofac](https://code.google.com/archive/p/autofac/wikis/GettingStarted.wiki) and then use its [MEF integration](https://code.google.com/archive/p/autofac/wikis/MefIntegration.wiki) to make the autofac components available to MEF.

Comment: Thank you for this concise list of options.

Comment: @WimCoenen I think for MEF 2 your own article might be better: http://mindinthewater.blogspot.nl/2011/03/mef-attribute-less-registration.html

Comment: @Zidad: Thanks for the remark, I've updated this (old) answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but I don't think that's possible to do with MEF.  One pattern to use to provide similar behavior though is the factory / provider pattern.

```
interface IData {} 

interface IDataProvider {
  IData Data { get; set; }
}

[Export(IDataProvider)]
class DataProvider : IDataProvider {
  public IData { get; set; }
}
```

You can use this pattern to dynamically update the implementation of `IData` to the value you would like to use.